# Constraining stdin in Python, v2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, io, portability

[Rags, again.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264920/why-doesnt-the-enter-key-send-eol)

---

This is the [rewrite](http://pastebin.com/We6JuXqr) of [Read stdin like a dictator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118721/read-stdin-like-a-dictator).

From that post:

> All too often I find myself wanting to allow only a certain list of characters to be written to stdin, and only recently did I actually bother to implement it. In Python, of all languages!
>
> Essentially, this module provides a few APIs that allow a very tailored approach to reading characters from a terminal. By intercepting individual keypresses at the instant they occur, we can make cool decisions about closing the input stream whenever we want -- we dictate who says what in our terminal!
>
> The standard input stream, after being opened, can be closed after a number of characters, or, at caller's option, any combination of a number of characters and allowed inputs.

... Yep, all still true, just way better, and actually cross-platform now.

It might seem like there's a lot of dead code / overkill stuff here; that's because I'm about to shift its focus from "input-constrainer-thing" to "poor-man's libreadline/curses" and so there's some provisioning in effect, but nevermind that.

I *have* some unittests but I won't supply them because writing them for an IO module is a lot more work than they're worth at this point.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import struct
from platform import system
SYSTEM = system().lower()

class CHAR:
    """essentially an enum, to avoid clouding the ns"""
    NUL = chr(0)
    INT = chr(3)
    EOF = chr(4)
    BEL = chr(7)
    BKS = chr(8)
    LFD = chr(10)
    CRR = chr(13)
    ESC = chr(27)
    SPC = chr(32)
    DEL = chr(127)

    CONDS = [
        (lambda i, chars: i in chars),
        (lambda i, chars: i not in chars),
        (lambda *args, **kwargs: False),
    ]


def init(TERM_BUFSIZE=4096):
    """module initialiser: calls constructors so you don't have to
    you must call this before other functions!"""
    global reader
    reader = read_class(TERMCTL_SPECIAL_BUFSIZE=TERM_BUFSIZE)


def checkinit(func, *args, **kwargs):

    def isdefined(*args, **kwargs):

        if "reader" not in globals().keys():
            print("\n\tfatal: init() not called\n")
            msg = "must call init() first, or call init() again before {}()".format(func.__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return isdefined


class _nt_reader():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """reader on nt"""

        self.NAME = "NT"

        if SYSTEM != "windows":
            util.writer("\n\there be dragons; ye COWER in the SHADOW of", self.NAME, "\n\n")

        self.msvcrt = __import__("msvcrt")
        self.ctypes = __import__("ctypes")
        try:
            self.colorama  = __import__("colorama")
            self.colorama.init()
        except (AttributeError, ImportError):
            print(
            """
            you must install colorama to use this module on windows
            do this by:
            $ cd colorama
            $ python setup.py install
            """
            )
            exit(2)


    def getch(self):
        """use msvcrt to get a char"""
        return self.msvcrt.getch()

    def drain_buf(self):
        """while buffer, pseudo-nonblocking read bytes from buffer using msvcrt"""
        y = []
        while self.msvcrt.kbhit():
            y.append(self.msvcrt.getch())
        return "".join(y)


class _posix_reader():

    def __init__(self, TERMCTL_SPECIAL_BUFSIZE=4096):
        """reader on posix"""

        self.NAME = "POSIX"

        if SYSTEM == "windows":
            util.writer("\n\there be dragons; ye COWER in the SHADOW of", self.NAME, "\n\n")

        self.tty     = __import__("tty")
        self.termios = __import__("termios")
        self.fcntl   = __import__("fcntl")

        self.O_NONBLOCK = __import__("os").O_NONBLOCK

        self.TERM_BUFSIZE = TERMCTL_SPECIAL_BUFSIZE

    def getch(self):
        """use old fashioned termios to getch"""
        if sys.stdin.isatty():  # fixes "Inappropriate ioctl for device"
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = self.termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                self.tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                self.termios.tcsetattr(fd, self.termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
                return ch
        else:
            return sys.stdin.read(1)

    def drain_buf(self):
        """read TERM_BUFSIZE of waiting keypresses"""
        if sys.stdin.isatty():
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            fl = self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_GETFL)
            self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | self.O_NONBLOCK)
            try:
                # if nothing is waiting on sys.stdin, then TypeError
                # because "can't concat NoneType and str"
                chars = sys.stdin.read(self.TERM_BUFSIZE)
            except TypeError:
                chars = ""
            finally:
                self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_SETFL, fl) # restore settings
                return chars
        else:
            return sys.stdin.read(self.TERM_BUFSIZE)  # ???

read_class = {
    "windows": _nt_reader,
}.get(
    SYSTEM,
    _posix_reader  # default
)


class util():
    """utilities"""
    def parsenum(num):
        """sys.maxsize if num is negative"""
        num = int(num)
        return sys.maxsize if num < 0 else num

    def writer(*args):
        """write a string to stdout and flush.
        should be used by all stdout-writing"""
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("writer requires at least one argument")
        if len(args) > 1:
            args = " ".join(str(i) for i in args).strip(" ")
        else:
            args = "".join(str(i) for i in args)
        sys.stdout.write(args)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def esc_filter(x, y):
        """append x to y as long as x is not DEL or backspace or esc"""
        if x in (CHAR.DEL, CHAR.BKS):
            try:
                y.pop()
            except IndexError:
                pass
            return y

        y.append(x)
        return y


@checkinit
def readkey(raw=False):
    """interface for getch + drain_buf
    if raw, behave like getch but with flushing for multibyte inputs"""
    ch = reader.getch()
    more = reader.drain_buf()

    if raw:
        return ch + more

    # cooked

    if ch == CHAR.INT: raise KeyboardInterrupt
    if ch == CHAR.EOF: raise EOFError

    if ch in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL):
        util.writer(CHAR.BKS + CHAR.SPC + CHAR.BKS)
        return CHAR.BKS

    elif ch in (CHAR.CRR, CHAR.LFD):
        util.writer(CHAR.CRR if SYSTEM == "Windows" else "")
        return CHAR.LFD

    elif ch == CHAR.ESC:
        if more:
            if more[0] == "[":
                sp = more[1:]
                if sp in ("D", "C"):
                    return "\033[" + sp

                elif sp == "3~":
                    return CHAR.SPC

                else:
                    return CHAR.BEL
            else:
                return CHAR.ESC + more

    ch += more
    return ch


@checkinit
def raw_readkey():
    """alias for readkey(raw=True)"""
    return readkey(raw=True)


@checkinit
def pretty_press(raw=False):
    """literally just read any fancy char from stdin let caller do whatever"""
    y = []
    i = readkey(raw=raw)
    if (not raw) and (i not in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL, CHAR.ESC)):
        util.writer(i)
    return util.esc_filter(i, y)


@checkinit
def _do_condition(
        end_chars,
        end_condition,
        count,
        ignore_chars=(),
        ignore_condition=CHAR.CONDS[True + 1],  # always false
        raw=False
    ):
    """singular interface to reading strings from readkey, to minimise duplication"""
    y = []
    count = util.parsenum(count)
    while len(y) <= count:
        i = readkey(raw=raw)
        if end_condition(i, end_chars):
            break
        if not ignore_condition(i, ignore_chars):
            if (not raw) and (i not in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL)):
                util.writer(i)
            y = util.esc_filter(i, y)
    return "".join(y)


@checkinit
def thismany(count, raw=False):
    """read exactly count chars"""

    return _do_condition(
        "",
        CHAR.CONDS[True + 1],  # more than true == never expires :D
        count,
        raw=raw
    )


@checkinit
def until(chars, invert=False, count=-1, raw=False):
    """get chars of stdin until any of chars is read,
    or until count chars have been read, whichever comes first"""

    return _do_condition(
        chars,
        CHAR.CONDS[invert],
        count,
        raw=raw
    )


@checkinit
def until_not(chars, count=-1, raw=False):
    """read stdin until any of chars stop being read,
    or until count chars have been read; whichever comes first"""

    return until(
        chars,
        invert=True,
        count=count,
        raw=raw
    )


@checkinit
def ignore(
        ignore_these,
        end_on,
        end_cond=True,
        count=-1,
        raw=False,
        invert=False
    ):
    """ignore_these keypresses, and stop reading at end_on or count,
    whichever comes first"""

    return _do_condition(
        end_on,
        CHAR.CONDS[not end_cond],
        count,
        ignore_chars=ignore_these,
        ignore_condition=CHAR.CONDS[invert],
        raw=raw
    )


@checkinit
def ignore_not(
        ignore_these,
        end_on,
        end_cond=True,
        count=-1,
        raw=False
    ):
    """ignore everything that isn't these keypresses
    and stop reading at end_on or count, whichever comes first"""

    return ignore(
        ignore_these,
        end_on,
        end_cond=end_cond,
        count=count,
        raw=raw,
        invert=True
    )
```

A trivial example of how this might be used:

```
>>> from pmlr import *
>>> init()
>>> print("enter your age:", end=" "); x = until_not("0123456789", count=2)
enter your age: 123<"a" pressed>
>>> x
123
```

It may seem like I'm abusing OOP and classes but those are partially for namespace-hygiene and partially because the way I did it previously was *really* fragile.

Additionally, `self.NAME` is for debugging, mostly, but I left it in for the same reason `read_class` is public and asking to be fiddled with: why not?

Finally, there is a "magic number" **4096**. That's from [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264993/136107) by the creator of `xterm`.

You can [get this on github](https://github.com/catb0t/pmlr), colorama included.

Answer (score 3):

**Take care of the docs**

Please avoid destroying your documentation after writing it. `checkinit` destroys the documentation of the functions it is applied to. You should use `functools.wraps`.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. I'll look into it

Comment: @cat Please unaccept this answer as more comprehensive ones are probably coming

Comment: [Whose choice is accepting an answer?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3915/136107) For now, I'll accept this one, as it's pretty valuable to me. If new ones appear, I'll change it.

Comment: @cat Ok, of course it is your choice. Just keep in mind that waiting some time before accepting an answer is standard practice here.

Answer (score 0):

I've always hated when there is a program that requires me to call some setup function before doing anything.  I also dislike when the module keeps some global state and everything is constrained by that. I think a much cleaner solution is something like this.

```
_readers = {}

def get_reader(buffer_size=4096):
    if buffer_size not in _readers:
        if SYSTEM == 'windows'
            _readers[buffer_size] = _nt_reader(buffer_size)
        else:
            _readers[buffer_size] = _posix_reader(buffer_size)
    return _readers[buffer_size]
```

This gives us two things - the first, is that we don't need some global variable that the user then accesses, and also (if they so desire) gives them multiple readers of different buffer size, if that were to matter.  This will require restructuring a lot of other code to not rely on a global variable.  Also, it may be worthwhile to make all other global names prefixed with an `_` so they aren't imported by `from x import *`, or make an `__all__` list.

The first thing we'll have to do to get rid of that global state is move all of those functions that rely on global state into a class - we'll make a base class that encompasses them.

```
class _ReaderBaseClass:

    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def getch(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def drain_buf(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def newline(self):
        return NotImplemented
```

From here, we'll need to add the other functions in as methods - I'll take those one by one.

**`readkey`**

I don't have a lot of specific suggestions here, except that you should return `self.newline` in the case of a carriage return or line feed - this way you abstract that away to the subclass.

**`_do_condition`**

```
ignore_condition=CHAR.CONDS[True + 1], # always false
```

This is a massive code smell - if it is always `False`, then just say `False`.  I'm more confused, though, because `True + 1` is `2`, which is `True`... then once I actually go and look at what that returns, I realize the lambda this returns is always false.  Then you should actually just do `CONDS[2]`, or even better you should define these lambdas as named functions somewhere so they're actually understandable.  They really don't belong in `CHAR` - I just made them static methods of the base class, but they could be just normal functions if you want.

**overall**

In general, avoid the hacky indexing by booleans - afaik that they have numeric values of 0 and 1 is a CPython implementation detail (I might be wrong about this), and either way is horrifically unreadable.

I fear that maybe you've tried to get to be too generic using `_do_condition` as well - it has gotten to the point that the other functions are fairly hard to read. I don't have a good suggestion for this, and if you find it workable then keep going, but there is a balance you have to strike, and I'm not sure you're there.

It also bothers me that a `reader` actually writes something - imo it should only return values, and then the caller should display them, if at all.  Otherwise, you should allow another parameter of an output stream for them to enter - they might not want to print to stdout by default.

#### Miscellaneous

Why are you making `CHAR` a class (and not an `Enum`)?  You're on Python 3, so unless you're using 3.3 or below for some reason (please don't) you have access to the [enum module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

You actually have a bug - your `util` class's methods should all be static methods - as is, you have instance methods with strangely named parameters (i.e. you're using `num` instead of `self`).

I also feel like these might be worth making helper functions in `reader` instead of some `util` class.

Here is the complete code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import abc
import sys
import struct
from platform import system
SYSTEM = system().lower()


class CHAR:
    NUL = chr(0)
    INT = chr(3)
    EOF = chr(4)
    BEL = chr(7)
    BKS = chr(8)
    LFD = chr(10)
    CRR = chr(13)
    ESC = chr(27)
    SPC = chr(32)
    DEL = chr(127)

class _ReaderBaseClass:

    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def newline_char(self):
        return NotImplemented

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def getch(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def drain_buf(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @staticmethod
    def char_in_list(ch, chars):
        return ch in chars

    @staticmethod
    def char_not_in_list(ch, chars):
        return ch not in chars

    @staticmethod
    def return_false(*args, **kwargs):
        return False

    def readkey(self, raw=False):
        """interface for getch + drain_buf
        if raw, behave like getch but with flushing for multibyte inputs"""

        ch = self.getch()
        more = self.drain_buf()

        if raw:
            return ch + more

        # cooked

        if ch == CHAR.INT: raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if ch == CHAR.EOF: raise EOFError

        if ch in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL):
            util.writer(CHAR.BKS + CHAR.SPC + CHAR.BKS)
            return CHAR.BKS
        elif ch in (CHAR.CRR, CHAR.LFD):
            util.writer(self.newline)
            return CHAR.LFD
        elif ch == CHAR.ESC:
            if more:
                if more[0] == "[":
                    sp = more[1:]
                    if sp in ("D", "C"):
                        return "\033[" + sp
                    elif sp == "3~":
                        return CHAR.SPC
                    else:
                        return CHAR.BEL
                else:
                    return CHAR.ESC + more

        return ch + more

    def raw_readkey(self):
        """alias for readkey(raw=True)"""
        return self.readkey(raw=True)

    def pretty_press(self, raw=False):
        """literally just read any fancy char from stdin let caller do whatever"""
        i = self.readkey(raw=raw)
        if not raw and i not in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL, CHAR.ESC):
            util.writer(i)
        return util.esc_filter(i, [])

    def _do_condition(
            self,
            end_chars,
            end_condition,
            count,
            ignore_chars=(),
            ignore_condition=return_false,
            raw=False
        ):
        """singular interface to reading strings from readkey, to minimise duplication"""

        y = []
        count = util.parsenum(count)
        while len(y) <= count:
            i = self.readkey(raw=raw)
            if end_condition(i, end_chars):
                break
            if not ignore_condition(i, ignore_chars):
                if not raw and i not in (CHAR.BKS, CHAR.DEL):
                    util.writer(i)
                y = util.esc_filter(i, y)
        return "".join(y)

    def thismany(self, count, raw=False):
        """read exactly count chars"""

        return self._do_condition(
            "",
            _ReaderBaseClass.return_false,
            count,
            raw=raw
        )

    def until(self, chars, invert=False, count=-1, raw=False):
        """get chars of stdin until any of chars is read,
        or until count chars have been read, whichever comes first"""

        if invert:
            f = _ReaderBaseClass.char_not_in_list
        else:
            f = _ReaderBaseClass.char_in_list

        return self._do_condition(
            chars,
            f,
            count,
            raw=raw
        )

    def until_not(self, chars, count=-1, raw=False):
        """read stdin until any of chars stop being read,
        or until count chars have been read; whichever comes first"""

        return self.until(
            chars,
            invert=True,
            count=count,
            raw=raw
        )

    def ignore(
            self,
            ignore_these,
            end_on,
            end_cond=True,
            count=-1,
            raw=False,
            invert=False
        ):
        """ignore_these keypresses, and stop reading at end_on or count,
        whichever comes first"""

        if end_cond:
            end_condition = _ReaderBaseClass.char_in_list
        else:
            end_condition = _ReaderBaseClass.char_not_in_list

        if invert:
            ignore_condition = _ReaderBaseClass.char_not_in_list
        else:
            ignore_condition = _ReaderBaseClass.char_in_list


        return self._do_condition(
            end_on,
            end_condition,
            count,
            ignore_chars=ignore_these,
            ignore_condition=ignore_condition,
            raw=raw
        )

    def ignore_not(
            self,
            ignore_these,
            end_on,
            end_cond=True,
            count=-1,
            raw=False
        ):
        """ignore everything that isn't these keypresses
        and stop reading at end_on or count, whichever comes first"""

        return self.ignore(
            ignore_these,
            end_on,
            end_cond=end_cond,
            count=count,
            raw=raw,
            invert=True
        )


class _nt_reader(_ReaderBaseClass):

    @property
    def newline(self):
        return CHAR.CRR

    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        """reader on nt"""

        super().__init__(buffer_size)

        if SYSTEM != "windows":
            util.writer("\n\there be dragons; ye COWER in the SHADOW of NT\n\n")

        self.msvcrt = __import__("msvcrt")
        self.ctypes = __import__("ctypes")
        try:
            self.colorama  = __import__("colorama")
            self.colorama.init()
        except (AttributeError, ImportError):
            print(
            """
            you must install colorama to use this module on windows
            do this by:
            $ cd colorama
            $ python setup.py install
            """
            )
            exit(2)


    def getch(self):
        """use msvcrt to get a char"""
        return self.msvcrt.getch()

    def drain_buf(self):
        """while buffer, pseudo-nonblocking read bytes from buffer using msvcrt"""
        y = []
        while self.msvcrt.kbhit():
            y.append(self.msvcrt.getch())
        return "".join(y)


class _posix_reader(_ReaderBaseClass):

    @property
    def newline(self):
        return ""

    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        """reader on posix"""

        super().__init__(buffer_size)

        if SYSTEM == "windows":
            util.writer("\n\there be dragons; ye COWER in the SHADOW of POSIX\n\n")

        self.tty     = __import__("tty")
        self.termios = __import__("termios")
        self.fcntl   = __import__("fcntl")

        self.O_NONBLOCK = __import__("os").O_NONBLOCK

        self.TERM_BUFSIZE = TERMCTL_SPECIAL_BUFSIZE

    def getch(self):
        """use old fashioned termios to getch"""
        if sys.stdin.isatty():  # fixes "Inappropriate ioctl for device"
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = self.termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                self.tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                self.termios.tcsetattr(fd, self.termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
                return ch
        else:
            return sys.stdin.read(1)

    def drain_buf(self):
        """read TERM_BUFSIZE of waiting keypresses"""
        if sys.stdin.isatty():
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            fl = self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_GETFL)
            self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | self.O_NONBLOCK)
            try:
                # if nothing is waiting on sys.stdin, then TypeError
                # because "can't concat NoneType and str"
                chars = sys.stdin.read(self.TERM_BUFSIZE)
            except TypeError:
                chars = ""
            finally:
                self.fcntl.fcntl(fd, self.fcntl.F_SETFL, fl) # restore settings
                return chars
        else:
            return sys.stdin.read(self.TERM_BUFSIZE)  # ???


_readers = {}

def get_reader(buffer_size=4096):
    if buffer_size not in _readers:
        if SYSTEM == 'windows'
            _readers[buffer_size] = _nt_reader(buffer_size)
        else:
            _readers[buffer_size] = _posix_reader(buffer_size)
    return _readers[buffer_size]


class util():
    """utilities"""
    @staticmethod
    def parsenum(num):
        """sys.maxsize if num is negative"""
        num = int(num)
        return sys.maxsize if num < 0 else num

    @staticmethod
    def writer(*args):
        """write a string to stdout and flush.
        should be used by all stdout-writing"""
        if not args:
            raise TypeError("writer requires at least one argument")
        if len(args) > 1:
            args = " ".join(str(i) for i in args).strip(" ")
        else:
            args = "".join(str(i) for i in args)
        sys.stdout.write(args)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    @staticmethod
    def esc_filter(x, y):
        """append x to y as long as x is not DEL or backspace or esc"""
        if x in (CHAR.DEL, CHAR.BKS):
            try:
                y.pop()
            except IndexError:
                pass
            return y

        y.append(x)
        return y
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive review, despite that I really don't like your implementation and some suggestions. Also, please note the act of returning LFD vs CRR was [informed by the writer of xterm](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264923/136107). This is not about *printing*, it's about what that Enter key actually does.

Comment: @cat, sorry, what do you mean about LFD vs CRR? I don't believe that I misrepresented that point here.  Do you mind expanding on what exactly you dislike about my implementation?

Comment: @Dannno It *seems* like you're saying `self.newline` should be platform-dependent: "*...you should return self.newline in the case of a carriage return or line feed - this way you abstract that away to the subclass.*" Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @cat I see, my implementation differs from yours. I can fix that. I should have written that you always return a newline, but what you write is platform independent.

Comment: [In raw mode, I would expect 13, in cooked mode, 10. The question was about raw mode, of course. - Thomas Dickey](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264920/why-doesnt-the-enter-key-send-eol#comment458338_264923) That goes for both Windows and Posix

Comment: @cat it would be straightforward to give a raw and cooked newline property if you wanted